# using jquery validate to check for extra cfc call

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I am using jquery Validator to validate an email address, I am using a remote method on the email vallidation, so i added another addMethod with jquery Validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod("emailSpamming",function(value,element){
        var defvalue = $('#emailRegistration').val();
        var datastring = 'actionofemail=' + defvalue;
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url: '/services/mycfc.cfc?method=spamemailcheck',
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'true') {
                    return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            }     
        });
    });
```

the cfc function returns me true and false based upon this condition:

```
<cfif decide.mx_found eq 'true' and decide.smtp_check eq 'true' and decide.role eq 'false' and decide.disposable eq 'false'>
            <cfset valid="false">   <!--- email good --->
        <cfelse>
            <cfset valid="true">    <!--- email spammed --->
        </cfif>
```

and in my jquery validate for email i am using this code:

```
emailRegistration: {required:true,email:true,emailSpamming:true,
            remote:{
                    url: "/services/mycfc.cfc?method=checkEmailDupe",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                            return $("#emailRegistration").val();
                        }
                    }   
                }
            },
```

Messages

```
emailRegistration: {
                required: "Email address required",
                email: "Valid email required",
                remote: "Duplicate email address",
                AsciiNoSpace:"Only alphanumeric characters",
                emailSpamming: "Invalid email verification failed"
            },
```

But it shows the message and when i enter a invalid email, the message does not go away if i enter valid email address

Comment: Can you show us the code in this call `spamemailcheck`

Comment: sure, in my question, you see `<cfif` that is the code which is executing and it returns me wither '`true` or '`false`